# Permanent marking of volume in aluminium pot

Tags: boil-kettle, brewpot, mash-volume

This technique https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5arq.jpg, shows how is easy to do permanent markings in stainless steel pot. But what about aluminium ?

Does anyone know if it is possible (and safe) to use it in aluminium pots ?

[image]

Comment: Try it on the bottom exterior of you pot maybe...

Comment: Rather than mark my aluminum kettle, I purchased a metal yard stick and measures how many centimeters high each gallon from 3 to 7 was.

Comment: A quick google search for "etching aluminum with electricity" brings up several links that suggest it will work on any metal.

Comment: Oh wow that is brilliant, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Can anyone comment on the long-term effect on Stainless steel? Would this encourage rust?

Comment: We need John Palmer to answer this question about aluminum, and also tell us what he thinks about doing it to stainless steel.  Looks very nice!

Comment: Before you get too far, you need to decide if your etching will match cold volumes or hot volumes.  If room temp to boiling temp is 4%, then by the time you put 9 gallons in there, you're looking at the difference between 9 and 9.36.

Comment: @Dale: Yes, but in my case this 4% isn't so relevant to my proccess, where I always adjust the wort gravity adding cold water, after it's ready to inoculate the yeast. So, just reading an approximate measure of the volume (cold or boiling) is enough and very useful, instead of estimating with the eyes or calculating with rules.

Comment: @brewchez: Maybe but... is it safe ? Toxic gases ? Acids ? Well... Now I miss having taken a MacGyver course ;) - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGyver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electro-etching works with all metals, including Aluminum.

Often, the makeup of the electrolyte is changed up to give better or worse results with different metals. In this case, you don't actually need an acid as per the above - just a salt water solution works fine for aluminum.

However, please make sure to do this in a well ventilated area as electro-etching with table salt (NaCl) will result in small amounts of chlorine gas being produced, and that certainly is not good for you to inhale.

I would recommend you test on the bottom of your pot to be sure you have your process down before etching the interior. While it's a relatively straightforward process, some experimentation in a non-visible area will help you get an idea of how long it will take to get an etch of sufficient depth / color.

Once you've etched the pot, boil a full pot of water for 20-30 minutes to re-establish your aluminum oxide layer in the areas you've etched. Note that this may make your etch a little harder to make out, but that's unavoidable.

Comment: I though that the aluminium oxide layer could reduce the visibility of etching, but who knows whether it still useful ?

Comment: I believe you are right; you need to overcome the issue with depth.